# How to handle mjpeg stream with okhttp?

Tags: mjpeg, okhttp

I can't get how to configure the OkHttpClient.
I've got a timeout on execute()

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use retrofit and found that @Streaming can't be used with RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL 
That was the issue!

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/561